# How to configure pycodestyle in Google App Store Cloud Shell

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell, pycodestyle

Yesterday my python scripts in Google Cloud Shell started to include the following pycodestyle warnings about the length of the lines:

`[pycodestyle] E501 line too long (85 > 79 characters)`

Whilst some of the warnings/comments were useful some were just annoying, I would like to be able to configure the warnings, e.g. extend the acceptable length to be longer than 79 characters.  Is it possible to include a setup.cfg, or similar, to configure these warnings, and where would it need to go in the Cloud Shell directory structure ?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible.

You could add a `~/.config/pycodestyle` file with something like:

```
[pycodestyle]
max-line-length = 100
```

There are other options, too, see [Configuration](http://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration).

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the pycodestyle file, but from your link I created a tox.ini file with the setting and it worked.  Thanks for your help